# Django не использует auth_user, а создает новую таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, django

Есть б/д, в которой есть таблица auth_user, и в неё необходимо заносить данные из формы. В models.py прописываю класс auth_user, создаю форму, которая отображается. Однако, после миграции, создаётся новая таблица asdf_auth_user, в которую заносятся данные, хотя необходимо их заносить в уже существующую таблицу auth_user. В Django я только начинающая.

Расположение файлов:

```
project1:
- qwe (папка)
- asdf (папка)
- db.sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать свою модель пользователя, просто наследуетесь от `AbstractUser`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    # ...
```

И затем указать её в настройках проекта `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'asdf.MyUser'
```

Также не забудьте зарегистрировать её в `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import MyUser

admin.site.register(MyUser, UserAdmin)
```

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user).

Comment: Мне следует просто вставить в settings.py в любое место AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'asdf.MyUser' ?

Comment: @ElenaDyagtereva Если её там нет, то да. Иначе, просто исправляете на свою.

Comment: После проделанных манипуляций и после введения данных, должна ли появиться соответствующая запись в auth_user? В моем случае просто появилась новая запись в таблице asdf_myuser, но в auth_user Ничего не изменилось и не добавилось

Comment: @ElenaDyagtereva А ваша конечная цель: расширить стандартную модель пользователя?

Comment: Нет, просто на главную страницу вывести поля ввода (регистрация) нового пользователя в auth_user.